# MongoDB query to get count of records matching a condition

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We have collection name CarProfile in Azure MongoDB with below documents.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "sunil"
    "Cars": [{
            "CarName": "skoda",
            "type": "Petrol",
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Kumar"
    "Cars": [{
            "CarName": "skoda",
            "type": "Petrol",
        },
        {
            "CarName": "benz",
            "type": "Petrol",
        }
    ]
}
```

Using below query, I can get count of records who has Id = 2 and name = kumar.

```
db.getCollection('Carprofile').find({id:2,name:"Kumar"}).count()
```

How can we write a MongoDB query to get count of cars for profile with Id = 2 and name = kumar
Result = 2 as there are two cars(skoda & benz)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this aggregation query:

- First `$match` by your desired values.
- Then `$project` to output only the size of the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Kumar"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "size": {
        "$size": "$Cars"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QXTYrKODOQP)

Comment: Thanks for help. It works like charm.  I am trying to call this query from C# Mongo APIs. can you please help me in this regard